# May I Add Something to the Top Bar?

Tags: top-bar

I wrote a basic script with JavaScript that answering to "What the day of the year are we in?" question. How may I add the value coming from this script to the top bar of Ubuntu?

[image]

For example I want to add `DAY: 150` or `DAY: 120` or something like this to the right side of the date having in top bar. How may I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try some extensions that are designed for this, [Argos by pew](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1176/argos/) or [Command Output by elken](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/912/command-output/).